# connect to mysql via spark jdbc connector

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark

Hey I have an EMR cluster  with spark 1.5.0 installed on it.

I'm trying to connect to one of our table in RDS and pull some data.
I downloaded the latest jar file from the official mysql site (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
I downloaded and untarred the file put it /home/hadoop/connectors and added this path in spark-defaults.conf file.

I manage to create a dataframe with this connection

```
df=sqlContext.read.format('jdbc')
   .options(url="jdbc:mysql://dw-mysql-replica.gtforge.com:3306/dwh?
         user=  <usr>l&password=<pass>", 
         dbtable='<table>')
   .load()
```

and manage to print the schema

```
df.printSchema()
```

but when I tried to materialized this data frame (AKA df.take(1) or df.collect() ) it throws the following error:

```
"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://dw-mysql-
 replica.gtforge.com:3306...."
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried explicitly providing a driver class?

Comment: spark-defaults.conf file i added the path to the jar file to spark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraClassPath. when I added the "driver" option in the options part (i.e `sqlContext.read.format('jdbc')
   .options(url="jdbc:mysql://dw-mysql-replica.gtforge.com:3306/dwh?
         user=  <usr>l&password=<pass>", 
         dbtable='<table>', driver="mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"`
nothing worked...

Comment: Driver option is wrong. It should be driver class - `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in this case.